# How do I list a directory in a Git repository together with the latest commit info for each directory entry?

Tags: git

I want to list a directory from a Git repository together with the latest commit information of each directory entry. Similiar to how GitHub displays directories or how viewvc displays a directory in an SVN/CVS repository.

Currently I do it like this:

1. Get the directory entries with `git ls-tree master` and parse the directory structure from the output.
2. Then for each directory entry I do this: `git log -n 1 master -- filename` and parse the commit information from it (I specify a special format string to make this easier, but this isn't relevant to my problem).

It's pretty obvious that this is very slow, because I have to call Git for each file. Is there a faster way to do this? Maybe a single command I can execute to get all the data I need at once?

Answer (score 4):

Oneliner to parse `git whatchanged` output and print tree annotated with recent commit ids:

```
git whatchanged -r --pretty=oneline | perl -ne 'our %q; if (/^([0-9a-f]{40})/) {$c = $1} if (/:.{38}(.*)/) { $q{$1} = $c unless exists $q{$1} }; END { print map {"$q{$_} $_\n"} (keys %q); }'  | sort -k 2
```

Example output:

```
b32f7f65f19e547712388d2b22ea8d5355702ce2 code/unfreezemodule/file.c
b32f7f65f19e547712388d2b22ea8d5355702ce2 code/unfreezemodule/Makefile
b32f7f65f19e547712388d2b22ea8d5355702ce2 code/unfreezemodule/unfreezemodule.c
efeda0a22e4d1d5f3d755fee5b72fa99c0046e38 code/unfreezer/.gitignore
b822361ffbc4548d918df5381ce94c296459598a code/unfreezer/unfreezer.c
18ed76836182eba702e89b929eff2c0ea78ffb3e code/whole/wh
1e111ce4e8c0813b397f34e3634309f7594cb864 code/xbmctest/.gitignore
cb67943c4c18e3461267a34935fc8efaca5e2166 .config/awesome/awesome.lua
d5e2b7c1d24bed1d0b53338f43747dc856c9cfe4 .config/awesome/rc.lua
13ca8dbcd7f1ec684a7eba494442ee743ed577c0 cr
566b54fb72e32947fcbf7d5c58fed78b5abe976d d
392ac1a2456e8a29b2ebb7af9499c3f69d24a559 Desktop/CityInfo.desktop
392ac1a2456e8a29b2ebb7af9499c3f69d24a559 Desktop/.directory
```

You can adjust `git whatchanged` parameters and/or filter the output as you want.

Comment: This command always prints all latest changes of the whole tree. Is there some option to only list changes in a specific directory? When the project is pretty large and I only want to list a small directory then I guess it would be pretty slow getting the data for the whole tree and then filter out anything I don't need.

Comment: You can filter paths after "git whatchanged part" with grep or perl or whatever. Example: `git whatchanged -r --pretty=oneline | perl -ne 'print if /[0-9a-f]{40} /; print if m!(?:\S+\s+){5}some_dir/!' | ....`. But resource economy is not going to be very big.

Comment: This script can also be modified to print two last commit ids per file, for example...

Comment: You can also 1. limit number of commits to search deep into, 2. Cache the first phase result somewhere and generate reports against it without re-running `git whatchanged` again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps parse `git whatchanged master`, continuing to go backwards in history until you've "seen" all file paths?

Depending on how long your history is and how old some files are, this might be faster.

Comment: Let's assume the history is big and there are files and directories which have never changed after repository creation. So I had to parse the whole history to find all files. I guess that won't be faster then.

Comment: In that case, I'm not aware of any better solution (at least using the tools Git provides, rather than working directly with the object files). Since tree objects aren't tied to a particular branch, they don't reference commit info.

Answer (score 0):

You can request `git log -n 1 <file|directoryname>`.  Thus you can parse git-ls-tree in a non-recursive mode and only need to run it for every file/directory at the level you are at.

Comment: That's exactly what I do already as I have written in the question. The question was if there is a faster method.

Comment: Is it *one* invocation of Git for *all* files and directories in a directory?