# How would I list files for a given directory in a given branch with git?

Tags: git

Considering that `HEAD` refers to my current branch (which isn't necessary `master`), how would I list all versioned files of a given directory (without the full recursive content)?

What I have tried:

I did play with `git log` (as in "[git -> show list of files changed in recent commits in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083166/how-to-list-a-directory-in-a-git-repo-together-with-the-latest-commit-info-for-ea)", or "[How can I search Git branches for a file or directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372506/how-can-i-search-git-branches-for-a-file-or-directory)"), but somehow it always gives me too much details.

I just need the list of versioned files directly under one directory.

Answer (score 3):

I would try:

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD -- mydirectory/.
```

Note:

- the '`/.`' after `mydirectory` in order to list the tree (file and subdirectories) directly under '`mydirectory`'. Without the '`-r`' option, it won't be recursive.
- the '`--`' in order to clearly separate the git options and arguments from the file/directory passed at the end.